# ASP.NET using class(static methods) in .aspx design form's head section

Tags: asp.net, methods, frameworks, static, zurb-foundation

Basically I am trying to integrate Foundation 4 framework into ASP.NET project. I have made a class in App_Code where I have made static methods which contains all the css, js links. Now I want to use it in head tags in the .aspx file.
Partial Code:
*AppCore.cs*

```
    public class AppCore
    {       
       private static IDictionary<string, string> Dlink = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static AppCore()
    {

     //App Links
        Dlink.Add("js", "~/_Assets/js/");
        Dlink.Add("css", "~/_Assets/css/");
        Dlink.Add("img", "~/_Assets/img/");
    }


        public static string link(string i)
    {
        if (!Dlink.ContainsKey(i))
            return "N/A";
        else
            return Dlink[i];
    }
}
```

**I am able to use it inside body tags as**

```
<% AppCore.link("css")+"foundation.css";%>
```

**What I really want is to use it in the head like:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<% AppCore.link("css");%>foundation.css" />
```

Where am I failing?

Comment: Why are you unable to use it? What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: Note that the `~/` paths only work if that path is then processed by asp.net because the browser doesn't understand it. Basically it must be a path-property of a server control.

Comment: @Oded, I was not getting the added dictionary value. Instead, I was getting null.

Comment: @HansKesting, Yes, you are correct. And now am dealing with this *new* problem :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= AppCore.link("css") %>foundation.css" />
```

Put an `=` sign after `<%` and remove `;` from the end.

For client specific URL do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="<%= ResolveClientUrl(AppCore.link("css")) %>foundation.css" />
```

Comment: Thnx... this answer solved my initial problem. But I am running into another problem. As stated earlier by @Hans, ~/ is not understood by HTML. As the result, Although the link is embedded correctly, but with "~/" and which does not open. Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: @AbhishekDeb try `ResolveClientUrl()` http://weblogs.asp.net/gothicpanda/archive/2008/09/19/asp-net-tip-resolving-client-url-s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try with single quote ie: '' instead of double quote "" like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<% AppCore.link("css");%>foundation.css' />
```

Let me know if it works?

Comment: Its not working ... its giving this output: &lt;%AppCore.link(&quot;css&quot;);%>foundation.css